# HTML code dynamiccaly generated by JS not performing Interactive

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, laravel-blade, jquery-select2

I have a form wizard and I am trying to dynamically add select tags and I have added a click-to-add button to generate the HTML code snippet. However, the css styles and select-2 don't apply to the code generated by the js click event and the attached event to the dynamic code also doesn't fire when clicked.

I have tried rearranging the js files but can't figure out why it still doesn't work.

In my below laravel code snippet, I have placed the js implementation directly below jquery cos it was implemented using jquery but it still doesn't work.

```
@section('scripts')
<!-- BEGIN: Vendor JS-->
<script src="{{ asset('backend/app-assets/vendors/js/vendors.min.js') }}"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var maxWeek = 53;
        var i = 2;

        $('#btn-add-week').click(function () {
            var weekData = '<div>\
                <div class="row">\
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">\
                        <h4 class="mb-0">Week '+i+'</h4>\
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-remove-week"><i data-feather="minus"></i></button>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="mb-1 col-md-12">\
                        <label class="form-label" for="day-1">Day 1</label>\
                        <select class="select2 form-select" id="week-'+i+'-day-1-id" name="week_'+i+'_day_1_id[]" multiple>\
                            <option>Select Exercises</option>\
                            @foreach ($exercises as $exercise)\
                                <option value="{{ $exercise->id }}">{{ $exercise->title }}</option>\
                            @endforeach\
                        </select>\
                    </div>\
                </div>\
                <div class="row">\
                    <div class="mb-1 col-md-6">\
                        <label class="form-label" for="day-2">Day 2</label>\
                        <select class="select2 form-select" id="week-'+i+'-day-2-id" name="day_2_id[]" multiple>\
                            <option>Select Exercises</option>\
                            @foreach ($exercises as $exercise)\
                                <option value="{{ $exercise->id }}">{{ $exercise->title }}</option>\
                            @endforeach\
                        </select>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="mb-1 col-md-6">\
                        <label class="form-label" for="day-3">Day 3</label>\
                        <select class="select2 form-select" id="week-'+i+'-day-3-id" name="day_3_id[]" multiple>\
                            <option>Select Exercises</option>\
                            @foreach ($exercises as $exercise)\
                                <option value="{{ $exercise->id }}">{{ $exercise->title }}</option>\
                            @endforeach\
                        </select>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="mb-1 col-md-6">\
                        <label class="form-label" for="day-4">Day 4</label>\
                        <select class="select2 form-select" id="week-'+i+'-day-4-id" name="day_4_id[]" multiple>\
                            <option>Select Exercises</option>\
                            @foreach ($exercises as $exercise)\
                                <option value="{{ $exercise->id }}">{{ $exercise->title }}</option>\
                            @endforeach\
                        </select>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="mb-1 col-md-6">\
                        <label class="form-label" for="day-5">Day 5</label>\
                        <select class="select2 form-select" id="week-'+i+'-day-5-id" name="day_5_id[]" multiple>\
                            <option>Select Exercises</option>\
                            @foreach ($exercises as $exercise)\
                                <option value="{{ $exercise->id }}">{{ $exercise->title }}</option>\
                            @endforeach\
                        </select>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="mb-1 col-md-6">\
                        <label class="form-label" for="day-6">Day 6</label>\
                        <select class="select2 form-select" id="week-'+i+'-day-6-id" name="day_6_id[]" multiple>\
                            <option>Select Exercises</option>\
                            @foreach ($exercises as $exercise)\
                                <option value="{{ $exercise->id }}">{{ $exercise->title }}</option>\
                            @endforeach\
                        </select>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="mb-1 col-md-6">\
                        <label class="form-label" for="day-7">Day 7</label>\
                        <select class="select2 form-select" id="week-'+i+'-day-7-id" name="day_7_id[]" multiple>\
                            <option>Select Exercises</option>\
                            @foreach ($exercises as $exercise)\
                                <option value="{{ $exercise->id }}">{{ $exercise->title }}</option>\
                            @endforeach\
                        </select>\
                    </div>\
                    <hr class="text-primary">\
                </div>\
            </div>';

            if(i <= maxWeek) {
                i++;
                $("#week-data").append(weekData);
            }
            
        });

        $('.btn-remove-week').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            i--;
        });

    });
</script>
<!-- BEGIN Vendor JS-->

<!-- BEGIN: Page Vendor JS-->
<script src="{{ asset('backend/app-assets/vendors/js/forms/wizard/bs-stepper.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('backend/app-assets/vendors/js/forms/select/select2.full.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('backend/app-assets/vendors/js/forms/validation/jquery.validate.min.js') }}"></script>
<!-- END: Page Vendor JS-->

<!-- BEGIN: Theme JS-->
<script src="{{ asset('backend/app-assets/js/core/app-menu.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('backend/app-assets/js/core/app.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('backend/app-assets/js/scripts/customizer.min.js') }}"></script>
<!-- END: Theme JS-->

<!-- BEGIN: Page JS-->
<script src="{{ asset('backend/app-assets/js/scripts/forms/form-wizard.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('backend/app-assets/vendors/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}"></script>
<!-- END: Page JS-->
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'description' );

    $(window).on('load', function () {
        if (feather) {
            feather.replace({
                width: 14,
                height: 14
            });
        }
    })
</script>
@endsection

@section('content')
<!-- BEGIN: Content-->
<div class="app-content content ">
    <div class="content-overlay"></div>
    <div class="header-navbar-shadow"></div>
    <div class="content-wrapper container-xxl p-0">
        <div class="content-header row">
            <div class="content-header-left col-md-9 col-12 mb-2">
                <div class="row breadcrumbs-top">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <h2 class="content-header-title float-start mb-0">Workout Wizard</h2>
                        <div class="breadcrumb-wrapper">
                            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                                <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                                    <a href="{{ route('dashboard') }}">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                                    <a href="{{ route('workouts.index') }}">Workouts</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="breadcrumb-item active">
                                    Create Workout
                                </li>
                            </ol>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-body">
            <!-- Horizontal Wizard -->
            <section class="horizontal-wizard">
                <div class="bs-stepper horizontal-wizard-example">
                    <div class="bs-stepper-header" role="tablist">
                        <div class="step" data-target="#account-details" role="tab" id="account-details-trigger">
                            <button type="button" class="step-trigger">
                                <span class="bs-stepper-box">1</span>
                                <span class="bs-stepper-label">
                                    <span class="bs-stepper-title">Basic Details</span>
                                    <span class="bs-stepper-subtitle">Basic workout info</span>
                                </span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="line">
                            <i data-feather="chevron-right" class="font-medium-2"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="step" data-target="#personal-info" role="tab" id="personal-info-trigger">
                            <button type="button" class="step-trigger">
                                <span class="bs-stepper-box">2</span>
                                <span class="bs-stepper-label">
                                    <span class="bs-stepper-title">Workout Details</span>
                                    <span class="bs-stepper-subtitle">Workout schedule details</span>
                                </span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="line">
                            <i data-feather="chevron-right" class="font-medium-2"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="step" data-target="#address-step" role="tab" id="address-step-trigger">
                            <button type="button" class="step-trigger">
                                <span class="bs-stepper-box">3</span>
                                <span class="bs-stepper-label">
                                    <span class="bs-stepper-title">Address</span>
                                    <span class="bs-stepper-subtitle">Add Address</span>
                                </span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="line">
                            <i data-feather="chevron-right" class="font-medium-2"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="step" data-target="#social-links" role="tab" id="social-links-trigger">
                            <button type="button" class="step-trigger">
                                <span class="bs-stepper-box">4</span>
                                <span class="bs-stepper-label">
                                    <span class="bs-stepper-title">Social Links</span>
                                    <span class="bs-stepper-subtitle">Add Social Links</span>
                                </span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bs-stepper-content">
                        <div id="account-details" class="content" role="tabpanel"
                            aria-labelledby="account-details-trigger">
                            <div class="content-header">
                                <h5 class="mb-0">Basic Details</h5>
                                <small class="text-muted">Enter basic workout details</small>
                            </div>
                            <form>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="mb-1 col-md-12">
                                        <label class="form-label" for="title">Title</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Jumping Jack Pro Max" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="mb-1 col-md-12">
                                        <label class="form-label" for="description">Description</label>
                                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="description" name="description" placeholder="Enter Workout Description"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="mb-1 col-md-6">
                                        <label class="form-label" for="goal">Goal</label>
                                        <select class="select2 form-select" id="goal-id" name="goal_id">
                                            <option>Select Goal</option>
                                            @foreach ($goals as $goal)
                                                <option value="{{ $goal->id }}">{{ ucfirst($goal->title) }}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mb-1 col-md-6">
                                        <label class="form-label" for="level">Level</label>
                                        <select class="select2 form-select" id="level-id" name="level_id">
                                            <option>Select Level</option>
                                            @foreach ($levels as $level)
                                                <option value="{{ $level->id }}">{{ ucfirst($level->title) }}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="mb-1 col-md-6">
                                        <label class="form-label" for="bodyparts">Bodyparts</label>
                                        <select class="select2 form-select" id="bodypart-id" name="bodypart_id[]" multiple>
                                            <option disabled>Select Body Part</option>
                                            @foreach ($bodyparts as $bodypart)
                                                <option value="{{ $bodypart->id }}">{{ ucfirst($bodypart->title) }}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mb-1 col-md-6">
                                        <label class="form-label" for="equipment">Equipments</label>
                                        <select class="select2 form-select" id="equipment-id" name="equipment_id[]"multiple>
                                            <option disabled>Select Equipment</option>
                                            @foreach ($equipments as $equipment)
                                                <option value="{{ $equipment->id }}">{{ ucfirst($equipment->title) }}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-prev" disabled>
                                    <i data-feather="arrow-left" class="align-middle me-sm-25 me-0"></i>
                                    <span class="align-middle d-sm-inline-block d-none">Previous</span>
                                </button>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-next">
                                    <span class="align-middle d-sm-inline-block d-none">Next</span>
                                    <i data-feather="arrow-right" class="align-middle ms-sm-25 ms-0"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="personal-info" class="content" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="personal-info-trigger">
                            <div class="content-header">
                                <h5 class="mb-0">Workout Details</h5>
                                <small>Workout schedule details</small>
                            </div>
                            <form>
                                <div id="week-data">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                            <h4 class="mb-0">Week 1</h4>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="btn-add-week"><i data-feather="plus"></i></button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="mb-1 col-md-12">
                                            <label class="form-label" for="day-1">Day 1</label>
                                            <select class="select2 form-select" id="week-1-day-1-id" name="day_1_id[]" multiple>
                                                <option>Select Exercises</option>
                                                @foreach ($exercises as $exercise)
                                                    <option value="{{ $exercise->id }}">{{ $exercise->title }}</option>
                                                @endforeach
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="mb-1 col-md-6">
                                            <label class="form-label" for="day-2">Day 2</label>
                                            <select class="select2 form-select" id="week-1-day-2-id" name="day_2_id[]" multiple>
                                                <option>Select Exercises</option>
                                                @foreach ($exercises as $exercise)
                                                    <option value="{{ $exercise->id }}">{{ $exercise->title }}</option>
                                                @endforeach
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="mb-1 col-md-6">
                                            <label class="form-label" for="day-3">Day 3</label>
                                            <select class="select2 form-select" id="week-1-day-3-id" name="day_3_id[]" multiple>
                                                <option>Select Exercises</option>
                                                @foreach ($exercises as $exercise)
                                                    <option value="{{ $exercise->id }}">{{ $exercise->title }}</option>
                                                @endforeach
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="mb-1 col-md-6">
                                            <label class="form-label" for="day-4">Day 4</label>
                                            <select class="select2 form-select" id="week-1-day-4-id" name="day_4_id[]" multiple>
                                                <option>Select Exercises</option>
                                                @foreach ($exercises as $exercise)
                                                    <option value="{{ $exercise->id }}">{{ $exercise->title }}</option>
                                                @endforeach
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="mb-1 col-md-6">
                                            <label class="form-label" for="day-5">Day 5</label>
                                            <select class="select2 form-select" id="week-1-day-5-id" name="day_5_id[]" multiple>
                                                <option>Select Exercises</option>
                                                @foreach ($exercises as $exercise)
                                                    <option value="{{ $exercise->id }}">{{ $exercise->title }}</option>
                                                @endforeach
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="mb-1 col-md-6">
                                            <label class="form-label" for="day-6">Day 6</label>
                                            <select class="select2 form-select" id="week-1-day-6-id" name="day_6_id[]" multiple>
                                                <option>Select Exercises</option>
                                                @foreach ($exercises as $exercise)
                                                    <option value="{{ $exercise->id }}">{{ $exercise->title }}</option>
                                                @endforeach
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="mb-1 col-md-6">
                                            <label class="form-label" for="day-7">Day 7</label>
                                            <select class="select2 form-select" id="week-1-day-7-id" name="day_7_id[]" multiple>
                                                <option>Select Exercises</option>
                                                @foreach ($exercises as $exercise)
                                                    <option value="{{ $exercise->id }}">{{ $exercise->title }}</option>
                                                @endforeach
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <hr class="text-primary">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-prev">
                                    <i data-feather="arrow-left" class="align-middle me-sm-25 me-0"></i>
                                    <span class="align-middle d-sm-inline-block d-none">Previous</span>
                                </button>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-next">
                                    <span class="align-middle d-sm-inline-block d-none">Next</span>
                                    <i data-feather="arrow-right" class="align-middle ms-sm-25 ms-0"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="address-step" class="content" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="address-step-trigger">
                            <div class="content-header">
                                <h5 class="mb-0">Address</h5>
                                <small>Enter Your Address.</small>
                            </div>
                            <form>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="mb-1 col-md-6">
                                        <label class="form-label" for="address">Address</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="address" name="address" class="form-control"
                                            placeholder="98  Borough bridge Road, Birmingham" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mb-1 col-md-6">
                                        <label class="form-label" for="landmark">Landmark</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="landmark" id="landmark" class="form-control"
                                            placeholder="Borough bridge" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="mb-1 col-md-6">
                                        <label class="form-label" for="pincode1">Pincode</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="pincode1" class="form-control" placeholder="658921" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mb-1 col-md-6">
                                        <label class="form-label" for="city1">City</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="city1" class="form-control" placeholder="Birmingham" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-prev">
                                    <i data-feather="arrow-left" class="align-middle me-sm-25 me-0"></i>
                                    <span class="align-middle d-sm-inline-block d-none">Previous</span>
                                </button>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-next">
                                    <span class="align-middle d-sm-inline-block d-none">Next</span>
                                    <i data-feather="arrow-right" class="align-middle ms-sm-25 ms-0"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="social-links" class="content" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="social-links-trigger">
                            <div class="content-header">
                                <h5 class="mb-0">Social Links</h5>
                                <small>Enter Your Social Links.</small>
                            </div>
                            <form>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="mb-1 col-md-6">
                                        <label class="form-label" for="twitter">Twitter</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="twitter" name="twitter" class="form-control"
                                            placeholder="https://twitter.com/abc" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mb-1 col-md-6">
                                        <label class="form-label" for="facebook">Facebook</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="facebook" name="facebook" class="form-control"
                                            placeholder="https://facebook.com/abc" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="mb-1 col-md-6">
                                        <label class="form-label" for="google">Google+</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="google" name="google" class="form-control"
                                            placeholder="https://plus.google.com/abc" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mb-1 col-md-6">
                                        <label class="form-label" for="linkedin">Linkedin</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="linkedin" name="linkedin" class="form-control"
                                            placeholder="https://linkedin.com/abc" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-prev">
                                    <i data-feather="arrow-left" class="align-middle me-sm-25 me-0"></i>
                                    <span class="align-middle d-sm-inline-block d-none">Previous</span>
                                </button>
                                <button class="btn btn-success btn-submit">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <!-- /Horizontal Wizard -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END: Content-->
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
$('#btn-add-week').click(function () {
```

to this

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn-add-week', function () {
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this worked! However select2 doesn't seem to be applied to the select elements despite they having dynamic ids.

Comment: Hi, just saw your message now. Am glad it worked and you also marked my answer as correct. Are you still facing an issue with select2 on the comment above or that is now resolved too?

Comment: Yes, I'm still facing an issue with select2. Tried a few approach from what was suggested on SO but none worked for me so far.